# Test cases that run two different python scripts which are in different directories

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to run a .robot file to test two different python scripts, which are in different directories. My .robot file is in `/home/alperen/Desktop/scpTest` and it is as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test Cases ***
| Use Case 1 - Scp Test

| | [Documentation] | This .robot file tests the useCase1ScpTest.py by checking the stdout.

| | [Tags] | use case 1 | critical | scpTest

| | ${result}= | run process | python | /home/alperen/Desktop/scpTest/useCase1scpTest.py
| | Should be equal as integers | ${result.rc} | 0
| | Should be equal as strings | ${result.stdout} | Passed.


| Dummy test

| | [Documentation] | Dummy text

| | [Tags] | foo | bar | runScriptOnRemote

| | ${result}= | run process | python | /home/alperen/Desktop/runScriptOnRemote/masterScript.py
| | Should be equal as integers | ${result.rc} | 0
| | Should be equal as strings | ${result.stdout} | Passed.
```

If I run the code above, Dummy Test fails with a message "Failed. != Passed." because masterScript.py most probably prints "Failed." However, if I copy the masterScript.py to the same directory with my .robot file, Dummy Test results with a pass. Can anyone please help me understand why it happens? Is there a way to pass the Dummy Test without copying masterScript.py? Thanks in advance.

Edit: masterScript.py runs another script named hello.py (which prints "hello world") on a remote machine. If "hello world" is printed, then masterScript.py file prints "Passed." and "Failed." otherwise.

Comment: What does masterScript.py do? It can indeed print "Failed." in one directory and "Passed." in another.

Comment: Have you tried to start the masterScript manually from both directories? What are the outputs?

Comment: Running just masterScript.py from `/home/alperen/Desktop/runScriptOnRemote` works. However, running it from `/home/alperen/Desktop/scpTest` prints the following: `couldn't read file "hello.py": no such file or directory` and "Failed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified masterScript.py, which included something like

```
command = [ "python", "hello.py" ]
```

Changing `"hello.py"` to its full directory, something like `"/home/alperen/Desktop/runScriptOnRemote/hello.py"` worked, thanks to Psytho's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Run robot with the --pythonpath switch directing it to the masterScript.py path. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works